# Python, Glade, GTK+

Tags: python, gtk3, glade

I am struggling with my GTK GUI...

I made a GUI for lights and etc and so far "everything" works but I can't figur it out for a timer that will start the lights on a given time and end it. The left spinbutton is for the "start Hour" and the right one is for the "End Hour". every object has a checkbox for enabeling/disabeling of the timer, and everytime you put in or edit the time, you need to push on the ok button. can someone help me please?

```
import datetime
import gi
import time

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk, GObject, GLib





class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        gladeFile = "main.glade"
        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(gladeFile)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        self.window        = self.builder.get_object("Main")
        self.window.connect("delete-event", gtk.main_quit)
        self.window.show_all()
        self.window.set_decorated(False)
        self.labelClock  = self.builder.get_object("Time")
        self.labelDate   = self.builder.get_object("Date")
        self.Uur_LED_Aan = self.builder.get_object("Uur_LED_Aan")
        self.Uur_LED_Uit = self.builder.get_object("Uur_LED_Uit")
        self.Uur_Licht_Aan = self.builder.get_object("Uur_Licht_Aan")
        self.Uur_Licht_Uit = self.builder.get_object("Uur_Licht_Uit")
        self.Uur_Luik_Open = self.builder.get_object("Uur_Luik_Open")
        self.Uur_Luik_Dicht = self.builder.get_object("Uur_Luik_Dicht")

    def compare(self):
        ULA = self.OK()
        ULU = self.OK()
        start_hour = ULA
        start_minute = '00'
        end_hour = ULU
        end_minute = '00'

        start_time = int(start_hour) * 60 + int(start_minute)
        end_time = int(end_hour) * 60 + int(end_minute)
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now().hour * 60 + datetime.datetime.now().minute
        if start_time == current_time:
            print("LED ON")

        elif end_time == current_time:
            print("LED OFF")
        return True

    def ULED_Update(self):
        GLib.timeout_add(100, self.compare, True)





    def OK(self, button):
        ULA  = self.Uur_LED_Aan.get_value()
        ULU  = self.Uur_LED_Uit.get_value()
        ULIA = self.Uur_Licht_Aan.get_value()
        ULIU = self.Uur_Licht_Uit.get_value()
        ULO  = self.Uur_Luik_Open.get_value()
        ULD  = self.Uur_Luik_Dicht.get_value()

        print(ULA, ULU, ULIA, ULIU, ULO, ULD)
        return ULA, ULU, ULIA, ULIU, ULO, ULD


    def displayDate(self, state):
        Time_now = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
        self.labelDate.set_label(Time_now)
        return state,


    def displayclock(self, state):
        #  putting our datetime into a var and setting our label to the result.
        #  we need to return "True" to ensure the timer continues to run, otherwise it will only run once.
        Time_now = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        self.labelClock.set_label(Time_now)
        return state, Time_now

    # Initialize Timer
    def startclocktimer(self):
        #  this takes 2 args: (how often to update in millisec, the method to run)
        GLib.timeout_add(100, self.displayclock, True)

    def startDate(self):
        #  this takes 2 args: (how often to update in millisec, the method to run)
        GLib.timeout_add(100, self.displayDate, True)


    def Switch_LED(self, switch, gparam):
        if switch.get_active():
            state = "Led_On"
        else:
            state = "Led_Off"
        print("Led_Switch was", state)


    def Switch_Licht(self, switch, gparam):
        if switch.get_active():
            state = "Licht_on"
        else:
            state = "Licht_off"
        print("Licht_Switch was", state)

    def Luik_Open(self, button):
        state = "Rolluik_open"
        print(state)

    def Luik_Dicht(self, button):
        state = "Rolluik_dicht"
        print(state)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.startclocktimer()
    main.startDate()
    main.ULED_Update()
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what your actual question is.  Could you describe what happens when you run the code you posted, and how that differs from what you expect to happen?

Comment: i changed my code back how i was trying. I try to compare the live current time, for example : now it's 22H and my LED needs to go ON at 22H30 and needs to go OFF at 23H. I made a def called "compare" etc... . sorry for the bad explaind question and english.. i'm a bit tired too, was working on this GUI till 5H this morning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start a separated thread for updating the timer showing the time in a label in the GUI. I see an example there https://github.com/f4iteightiz/UWR_scoreboard